# Can I omit the word 'for' in a parallel structure?

Tags: prepositions, parallelism

For example in this sentence:

> Studies have shown that the benefits of environmental initiatives were actually higher for small companies **than** **for** big companies.

Is omitting the "for" in the phrase "than for" gramatically correct in extreme formal writing like below?

> Studies have shown that the benefits of environmental initiatives were actually higher for small companies **than** big companies.

Comment: You can delete practically anything that's repeated in a parallel construction. Certainly prepositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit words with ***than***, it is true, but when it gives way to ambiguities, it is better to leave words in for clarity. When you say:

> ...***the benefits of environmental initiatives*** were actually higher *for small companies* than ***big companies***.

it can be misunderstood as *benefits were higher than big companies*. Even if the symmetry of *small and big companies* clarifies to a certain extent which are the two elements compared, and the confusion is rather grammatical than semantic, I would still use the clearest grammatical formula. If you keep ***for***, any confusion is eliminated. Note that after *than*, more words are omitted:

> the benefits of environmental initiatives were actually higher ***for*** small companies ***than*** *[they were] <sub>(omitted)</sub>*  ***for*** big companies.

This is similar to the advice given by teacher Paul Fanning in ***[guinlist](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/tag/ellipsis-with-than/)*** about the sentence:

> ***Disruption*** was caused more ***by climate change*** *than* ***storms***.

He says:

> Does ***storms*** here contrast with ***disruption*** or ***climate change***? Is the unmentioned wording ***were*** after ***storms*** (saying disruption was the main result of climate change, not storms), or ***it was caused*** ***by*** after ***than*** (saying climate change was the main cause of disruption, not storms)? *Such double meanings are always a danger when ***than*** follows a verb and two nouns.* ***The way to prevent them is to leave fewer words unmentioned.*** For example, adding *by* before *storms* above would solve the problem instantly.